# Creating instance type after filter

Tags: scala, scala-collections, extends

I have a simple class which extends IndexedSeq[MyType]

```
class MyClass(someName: String, values: Iterable[MyType]) extends IndexedSeq[MyType] {
  val name = someName
  val rows = values.toVector
  ....
}
```

This works fine, allowing me to call all the standard collection methods on this object, filter, map etc and returning me the results as an IndexedSeq[MyType].

What I would like is for the results be returned as a new instance of MyClass or a boilerplate free way of doing this so I don't require the additional manual step each time of creating a new MyClass. EG:

```
val results = myClassInstance.filter(t => t)
val newMyClass = new MyClass(myClassInstance.name, results)
```

Is there any way of simplifying and doing something like the following, given that I need access to the original myClassInstance to copy the name value from it to the new object.

```
val newMyClass = myClassInstance.filter(t => t).toMyClass
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out the solution by extending `IndexedSeqLike[DataRow, DataView]` and implementing a builder in the companion object. So far this seems to do exactly what I was after without needing passthough calls.

```
class MyClass(someName: String, values: Iterable[MyType]) 
  extends IndexedSeq[MyType] 
  with IndexedSeqLike[MyType, MyClass] {

  val name = someName
  val rows = values.toVector

  // Supply a builder method which will get used on filter, reverse etc,
  override def newBuilder: mutable.Builder[MyType, MyClass] =
    MyClass.newBuilder(name)

  ....
}
```

Then in the companion object, add the following...

```
object MyClass {

  // Builder for a new MyClass instance.
  def newBuilder(name: String): mutable.Builder[MyType, MyClass] =
    Vector.newBuilder[MyType] mapResult (vector => new MyClass(name, vector))
}
```

Now the following work as required :

```
val filteredData: MyClass = myClass.filter(f => f)
val reversedData: MyClass = myClass.reverse
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need to inherit from IndexedSeq?

If you need only **filter** & **map** function in your class, you can implement them, without overriding IndexedSeq

```
class MyClass(name: String, values: Iterable[MyType]) {

    def filter(f: MyType => Boolean): MyClass = {
        new MyClass(name, values.filter(f))
    }

    def map(f: MyType => MyType): MyClass = {
        new MyClass(name, values.map(f))
    }

}
```

or If you really really need to override IndexedSeq, you can add explicit filter method to your class

```
class MyClass(name: String, values: Iterable[MyType]) extends IndexedSeq[MyClass] {

    def filterClass(f: MyType => Boolean): MyClass = {
        new MyClass(name, values.filter(f))
    }

}
```

Or another option

```
class MyClass(name: String, values: Iterable[MyType]) extends IndexedSeq[MyClass] {

    def copyWith(f: Iterable[MyType] => Iterable[MyType]): MyClass = {
        new MyClass(name, f(values))
    }

}

MyClass.copyWith(_.filter(...))
MyClass.copyWith(_.filterNot(...))
MyClass.copyWith(_.map(...))
```

Comment: This is probably the simplest solution. Although I really wanted all of the standard collection methods available as well. Slice, reverse, filterNot etc, plus any overloads without having to create pass-throughs for each one if this is possible.

Comment: Thought of another option :)

Comment: This was better, but still bit verbose. After a bit more investigation I found a neater solution. Thanks